# How do I set up a calendar in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to set up a calendar in access where I can put in Customer information for specific dates. I must be doing something wrong, please help.

The table list that I would like to link has these headers

```
 ID :Customer : Date: Status: Hours
```

example:

```
2:  Tax Services:   07-Mar-14   :completed: 11-12
5:  Discount Tire:  25-Mar-14:  Call
```

Comment: Please specify what "I must be doing something wrong" means. Are you getting an exception? Are you not getting the expected output? Something else is going wrong? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can create the form of a calendar but it is not interactive with my table....I can not input anything into the calendar

Answer (score 1):

In order for a data bound `Form` to be editable, the form must be either based on the table or on a query that is updatable.

A query is not updatable if it contains a `DISTINCT` clause (`Unique Records` property set to `Yes`) or if it is a `UNION` query or has a `GROUP BY` clause. Cross-table queries are not updatable. SQL Pass-Through queries are not updatable. A query joining tables containing a many-to-one-to-many relationship is not. A query containing aggregate functions (COUNT, SUM, MAX etc.). A query containing a sub-select in the field list.

The `Form` must have the `AllowEdits` property set to `Yes`. If you want to be able to add or remove records, also set the `AllowAdditions` and `AllowDeletions` properties to `Yes`.

Set `DataEntry` to `No` as this means that a new empty record is created each time you open the form.